# Window location replace for ppt

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have the below script on a page that redirects users to a chosen binary item (doc, docx, ppt, pptx, xls, xlsx).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.onload = function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            window.location.replace("<%=litLink.Text%>");
        }, 500);
    };
});
```

The user comes to this page, and redirects the user to a document. `litLink` contains the url of where the user should be redirected to. This works for PDFs, however when a user chooses a PPT/XLS/DOC file the page executes this script repeatedly. I have to close my browser for the downloads to stop.

How can I get around this? I want the document to download and then for the script to stop firing.

Comment: Then why are you calling `setInterval`?

Comment: The reason the PDF works is that the browser probably has support for viewing it in the browser so you get redirected and the code doesn't run anymore. For regular files the code downloads the file every 500ms. Not sure why you have an interval.

Comment: Thanks guys! I've accepted an answer but you were all right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you'd like to wait 500ms *once* before prompting the download, in which case you need to use [**`setTimeout`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout), not [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval):

```
$(window).on("load", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.replace("<%=litLink.Text%>");
    }, 500);
});
```

I also replaced the window.onload assignment with the equivalent jQuery form, since you're already using jQuery, so that you can attach multiple `load` events to `window` without replacing the currently set one.

Comment: Thank you mc10, brilliant answer. I like the way you've explained why my code wasn't working. My knowledge of JavaScript is a little flaky! :)